# What should be in io.connect() function?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am wondering what i should pass in args of the io.connect() function.
Documentations usually says "http://localhost".
But if i want to make it work not only in local, what should be passed as an argument ?

Thanks for your answers, StackOverflow user's are awesome !

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

Comment: It should be URL of your website.

Comment: If you are working on localhost it should be `localhost` otherwise it should be website url.

Comment: Do it needs the nodejs http server's port to be specified ? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, the port should be there along with url

Comment: you can simply use var socket = io();